Ошибка System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
Это тестовый код, по идеи он должен получать список с ссылки и делать из него список. После он должен найти в этом списке "BOB". Но вместо результата он показывает System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]:

using System.Management;
using System.Numerics;

string cpuID = string.Empty;

ManagementClass managClass = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
ManagementObjectCollection managCollec = managClass.GetInstances();

foreach (ManagementObject managObj in managCollec)
{
    cpuID = managObj.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
    break;
}
Console.WriteLine("PasteBin: " + new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(@"https://pastebin.com/raw/y4xtfJ6Q").Result);
Console.WriteLine("HWID: " + cpuID);

var people = new List<string>() { new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(@"https://pastebin.com/raw/y4xtfJ6Q").Result };

Console.WriteLine(people);

var containsBob = people.Contains("BOB");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, containsBob));


Ну так вы непойми зачем создаете коллекцию  (new List<string>()) в которую помещаете 1 строку, затем эту коллекцию выводите на экран (Console.WriteLine(people);), вам и делает people.ToString(), что по умолчанию дает название данного типа. Если вам надо вывести данные из коллекции, то проходитесь по ней циклом, либо используйте string.Join(), ну или отказывайтесь от коллекции, она бесполезна в данном коде.

Из замечаний: HttpClient - должен быть создан только один раз и существовать пока не закроется приложение. Вы сейчас под каждый вызов делаете новый объект, что очень плохо. .Result - это тоже очень плохо, научитесь делать нормальные асинхронные вызовы (async/await), где будет var result = await client.GetStringAsync(...);. Ну и последнее - странно читать одну и туж ссылку дважды...

Извините я не силен в c#, только учу его. Спасибо за советы но как можно это решить? Я хотел сделать проверку hwid`a при заходе в программу, если в пасте бин есть хвид то можно войти

Здесь не надо быть гуру C#, достаточно включить простую логику) Вот у вас на пастбине строка, вы ее криво косо получаете, ок, на скрине во видно даже значение (PasteBin: SAM). Вот дальше подумайте логически, зачем вы повторно получаете то, что уже получили, да еще и заносите это в коллекцию? Почему не занести то, что получили ранее в отдельную переменную (string pastbinResult = ....GetStringAsync(@"https://pastebin...);) и работать с ней? Использование коллекции ведь ну вообще не логично.

Я разобрался, всем спасибо! Я тупой, мог сделать через переменную но зачем то полез делать лист (список)

async/await научитесь использовать

Ты пытаешься вывести в виде строки сам список, вот он тебе и говорит, что у тебя список из одной строки. Обратись к его первому элементу:
Console.WriteLine(people); => Console.WriteLine(people[0]);
Так как отсчёт начинается с нуля, то ставим 0.
Если далее у тебя будет список большой, и тебе надо будет вывести что-то определенное, то можешь использовать что-то в этом роде:
int index = people.IndexOf("BOB");
Console.WriteLine(people[index]);

